# Create Global Variable for use in an IErrorHandler implementation

Tags: wcf

I need a way to pass IErrorHandlers HandleError method the data the user inputs.

When the service is called I want to set a session variable (or something like a session variable) populate it with user data. 
Then run the service method, if there is an error IErrorHandler catches it. In my HandleError method I want to be able to get the data out of the "session variable" then remove the session variable.

I was able to setup a way to populate a session variable, but this variable returns null when enetering my ErrorHandler class.

```
Process(Order o)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["InputData"] = o;
```

Can someone help me through a solution to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since all of this happens in the same request, you should not need a session variable.

Try creating a non-static member of the service class with the data you want. Set it at the beginning of the service operation. If the IErrorHandler determines that the error occurs in this service, then it should be able to retrieve the value.

Comment: public class OrderService : IOrderService
    {   public void SetSession(object value)
        {
           

        }
       
        public object GetSession()
        {
            return null;
        }

Comment: These methods cant be accessed in the ErrorHandler class which is in the same namespace. Im not sure why??

Comment: The name 'GetSession' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please show exactly how you are trying to use them. I bet you're not first getting an instance of the service class.

Comment: Im my ErrorHandler class even if I write  OrderService s = new OrderService();
object moomoo=  s.GetSession(); it returns null. I created a property like so in the OrderService where are the web methods are.. private object session=null;
        public void SetSession(object value)
        {
            session = value;
        }
        public object GetSession()
        {
            return session;
        }

Comment: You need to get a reference to the _current_ OrderService instance, not to a new one. Of course, the variable has never been set in the new instance, so it returns null.

Comment: In one og my methods I am writing the folowing in order to get to trigger HandleError method..SetSession(o);
            throw new ApplicationException();

Comment: how do I reference the current one?

Comment: The "this" keyword does not have the "GetSession()" function available in it

Comment: I believe you want [`OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575343.aspx).

Comment: OrderService s=(OrderService) OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(); throws an exception stating I cannot access a disposed object

Comment: Interesting. Can you show the code? There are two methods in `IErrorHandler` and it would be interesting to see which one you're using. I believe I saw an example of using it in the `ProvideFault` method.